# Implementing Regex In Bash

Tags: regex

I am trying to throw an error if my text file lines have any combination of 5 [A-Z 0-9] chars followed by a comma and nothing else, like this:

```
WH3Y4,
H7UF5,
```

but my code is showing the error even when the text lines look like this, with spaces and words after the comma:

```
WH3Y4, my test
H7UF5, your test
```

The regex I am using below should work, if I understand how this is done:

```
^ to indicate the beginning of the text line
[A-Z0-9]{5} to indicate 5 chars of either cap letter or numbers
, to indicate they are followed by a comma
$ to indicate the end of the text line
```

So in theory, when it encounters *any* text after the comma on the same line, it should not produce the error, yet that's what's happening:

```
if ! [[ $myText =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5},$ ]]; then
        echo "Error"
        continue
fi
```

Similarly, if I want to error when the text looks like this:

```
WH3Y4 test
H7UF5  test
```

this should work, but it doesn't either:

```
if ! [[ $myText =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5} *[A-Za-z]$ ]]; then
        echo "Error"
        continue
fi
```

And when I try this as suggested in the comments:

```
[[ "$myText" =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5},\$ ]]
```

it produces an error for this as it should:

```
WH3Y4, 
H7UF5,
```

but also produces an error for this as it shouldn't:

```
WH3Y4, my test
H7UF5, your test
```

I thought the idea of the $ is to indicate the end of the line, but if the line continues with more chars then it should not match the error condition.

Comment: I think you can put it in a variable `re='^[A-Z0-9]{5},$'` and then `if ! [[ $myText =~ re ]]; then`

Comment: So when I try: [[ "$myText" =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5},\$ ]] it also produces an error when it shouldn't, when the text lines have words after the comma like this: 4WA16B7V722EC,test

Comment: I thought the idea of the $ is to indicate the end of the line,so it's basically comma and end of line, but if the line continues with more chars then it should not match the error condition.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/fyNBBF

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's not clear to me how this works when the data is WH3Y4, my test because in that case it should not produce an error but still does. In other words, I want the error only when nothing is following the commas, but it's showing an error in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code is not implementing what you want. You say

```
I am trying to throw an error if my text file lines have any combination
of 5 [A-Z 0-9] chars followed by a comma and nothing else
```

but then your code says

```
if ! [[ $myText =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5},$ ]]; then
    echo "Error"
    continue
fi
```

The presence of the `!` - the negation operator - means that it will print "Error" if the string does *not* match the regex, so it will *accept* the two sample strings your gave - `WH3Y4,` and `H7UF5,` - and will *reject* anything else. I think what you wanted here is

```
if [[ $myText =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5},$ ]] ; then
    echo "Error"
    continue
fi
```

or in other words, just get rid of the `!`.

In the second case

```
if ! [[ $myText =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5} *[A-Za-z]$ ]]; then
  echo "Error"
  continue
fi
```

the problem is that your regular expression doesn't match your data. I suggest that you use

```
if [[ $myText =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5},[\ A-Za-z]+$ ]]; then
  echo "Error"
  continue
fi
```

Note that I dropped the `!` in the this case as well.

Comment: Oh my, so it's a rookie error?!?! Let me test and see but I suspect you might be right.

Comment: So starting with the first one, [[ $myText =~ ^[A-Z0-9]{5},$ ]], that does not produce the error for [WH3Y4,] when it should, so I'm stumped.